# Move files if ID in CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

We have a directory with files in the following format.

[id].mp4

We also have a list of ID's in the form of a CSV file.

We need to move all files with the corresponding ID to a different directory.

Can someone please explain how to do this with a bash script?

Comment: exactly, @Cyrus is right, and I made a mistake by giving you the answer. You should show us the effort you made first so that we can guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's easy, first of all extracts the IDs, and then moves the corresponding files to the desired directory.

something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

csv_file="path/to/ids.csv"
source_dir="path/to/source"
destination_dir="path/to/destination"

while IFS=',' read -r id; do
  #to remove double quotes from the ID
  id=$(echo "$id" | tr -d '"')
  
  file="${source_dir}/${id}.mp4"
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    mv "$file" "$destination_dir"
    echo "Moved file $file to $destination_dir"
  else
    echo "File $file not found"
  fi
done < "$csv_file"
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! Everything works as we need except that the CSV file has double quotes around the ID. So the filename ends up as "1".mp4 instead of 1.mp4.

Comment: you can use `tr -d '"'` to remove the double quotes from the ID before constructing the file path, I will update my answer!